# Add copyright header to compiled Angular app

Tags: angular

The website files that get compiled from building an Angular application with `ng build --prod` don't contain any copyright information, specifically those copyright headers that I add to my source code.

For example:

```
/*********
 * Copyright the current year Acme, Co.
 *********/
```

How do I add copyright header information to files from the ng CLI's production build output in an automatic way?

*The goal* is, for example, to modify the `dist/apps/myapp/main.js` file's copyright file header so that it looks the same as above.

I have tried concatenating a file with only the copyright header and the files output from the build process together at the end of the build, but that means I have to add steps to my release process, `ng build --prod; cat ...`, but I don't want to do that because it adds complexity to the build.

Comment: Can you add more information with example you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it in an "Angular" way: it depends on the version. For the latest verison, use angular-builder's custom-webpack.

- Angular 5 and below - eject from angular-cli
- Angular 6,7,8 *(3rd party)* - you could use the package [ngx-build-plus](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus) which lets you add some extra webpack stuff without ejecting
- Angular 7-current - use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack

I think the simplest webpack plugin/feature to add a comment to the top of an output file is `BannerPlugin` which you can read more about here https://webpack.js.org/plugins/banner-plugin/

Roughly to do this (have not tested) you would make a new file like `webpack.extra.js` and add the following:

```
const webpack = require('webpack'); module.exports = { plugins: [ new webpack.BannerPlugin('—– Some test comment for top of file —–') ] }
```

**For ngx-build-plus** you then pass this extra file on your next build:

`ng build –extra-webpack-config webpack.extra.js`

And the "Some test comment" should appear at the top of each chunk.

**For @angular's custom webpack builders** edit your `angular.json` file and add the path to your extra webpack config as `customWebpackConfig` [as per the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack#custom-webpack-browser) (good examples in there). Then when you `ng build`, the extra webpack config will be included and you will find the comment at the top of each chunk in the resulting build.

Comment: I don't think eject is supported in my version of Angular (7.x)

Comment: Fair point, to be honest I forgot they removed ng eject as I don't use it. I guess custom builders would be the closest thing to a replacement for eject

Comment: For Angular 8.x it appears as though https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack is the right plugin to use to add custom webpack configs

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add variables after it has been compiled please follow this tutorial https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-to-configure-your-angular-application-without-a-rebuild/

file: env.js

```
(function (window) {
  window.__env = window.__env || {};
  window.__env.apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080';
  window.__env.copyright= 'Copyright the current year Acme, Co.';
  window.__env.enableDebug = true;
}(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a node js task that will run after npm prod build and update all the js and css files with copyright text.

Create copyright.txt file in the same directory structure.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const Copyright = {
    _fs: null,
    _path: null,
    _config: {
        directory: './dist/'
    },
    _copyrightTextBuffer: null,
    _readCopyrightTextFromFile: function () {
        console.log(`Reading copyright text from ${__dirname}\\copyright.txt`);
        this._copyrightTextBuffer = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}\\copyright.txt`);
        console.info(`Copyright text is: \n ${this._copyrightTextBuffer}`);
    },
    _readFileRecusivly: function () {
        const self = this;
        const directoryPath = this._path.join(__dirname, this._config.directory);
        console.log(`Updaing js file inside ${directoryPath} directory.`);
        this._fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
            //handling error
            if (err) {
                return console.error('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
            }
            const jsFileRegex = new RegExp('\\.js$|\\.css$');
            files.forEach((file) => {
                // if file is only js type
                if (jsFileRegex.test(file)) {
                    self._updateFileWithCopyRight(file)
                }
            });
        });
    },
    _updateFileWithCopyRight: function (filename) {
        const file = this._path.join(__dirname, `${this._config.directory}\\${filename}`);
        var data = this._fs.readFileSync(file); //read existing contents into data
        var fd = this._fs.openSync(file, 'w+');
        fs.writeSync(fd, this._copyrightTextBuffer, 0, this._copyrightTextBuffer.length, 0); //write new data
        fs.writeSync(fd, data, 0, data.length, this._copyrightTextBuffer.length); //append old data
        // close the file descriptor
        fs.close(fd, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(`Failed to close the file: ${file}`);
            }
            console.log(`Udated the copyright text for '${file}' file`);
        });
    },
    init: function (fs, path, directoryPath) {
        this._fs = fs;
        this._path = path;
        this._config.directory = directoryPath ? directoryPath : this._config.directory;
        this._readCopyrightTextFromFile();
        this._readFileRecusivly();
    }
}

if (process.argv && process.argv.length === 3) {
    Copyright.init(fs, path, process.argv[2]);
} else {
    Copyright.init(fs, path);
}
```

Comment: that's an interesting way of doing it. i just wish there was a way to do it inside angular as part of the build process.

Comment: Yes, you can call this script as part of npm prod command